# give several subnet ip from one switch

Tags: switch, router, ip

I have a network and I have 2 subnets from ISP. Can I give these 2 IP to router from switch like it is shown in this figure:

[image]

I know, I can give to one physical port, but I want now about realisation like this. Will it work or not?

Comment: Only your ISP can answer whether they will deliver both subnets on the same physical link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your provider (ISP) allows you to split the two into VLAN's, for example the link to your provider to be configured as a trunk interface passing Vlan 10 and VLan 20 for example then you may do this either by two physical access ports back to the router ot another trunk on the switch and sub-interfaces on the router.

Or is the provider using the second IP as a secondary address? If so then this is not possible.